# App to Support Android 2.1 and Apps2SD

Tags: android, app2sd

I currently have an app which is set to support Android 2.2 and have the Android Manifest file the line of code to enable the app to be installed on to the SD Card. I want to be able to make the App also support Android 2.1 and above. Is there a way I can do this or do I need to have two separate apps. One for Android 2.1 and another for 2.2 and above.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
Simply in the Manifest editor add the uses-sdk in "Manifest extras" and set only the minSdkVersion attribute to an API version of your choice. Don't set the Targetsdkversion.

This works for my apps.

I set:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

and

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

You can find all this information on the [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: @EncricoOrs Thanks for the help. I have done what you have suggested but it is still throwing up the error about the InstallLocation Line. I have set in the project properties to target Android 2.1. If I set it to target Android 2.2 will people still be able to see it on the market if they are using 2.1

Comment: Yes. In the eclipse project properties you need to target Android 2.2 (API 8). You shuld see the Android 2.2 libraries added to the project.